# ESAPI properties file in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, esapi

I'm using ESAPI encryption in Tomcat war application. I want to load the ESAPI.properties file from a directory outside of the war, in order to have a different key and salt to each environment.
I also wish that each war will have a different ESAPI.properties file so each application will be individuality configured.
According to the documentation of org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration there are few ways to achive that.

1) SecurityConfiguration.setResourceDirectory( "C:\temp\resources" ).

2) System.getProperty( "org.owasp.esapi.resources" )

3) Inside the System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/.esapi" directory

4) The first ".esapi" or "esapi" directory on the classpath.

The first 3 options will enforce one configuration per tomcat. Meaning the properties file location is enforced on all deployed wars. (The first option uses ClassLoader.getSystemResource -requires the path to be part of the class path)

Is there a way to accomplish it using Tomcat configuration?

I also found a way to override ESAPI default security configuration, where I can extend the DefaultSecurityConfiguration and override getResourceFile, but ESAPI javadoc says that this method should "NEVER" be used - I'm not sure what is the reason for that.

```
 package org.owasp.esapi;
 public final class ESAPI{   
 /**
 * Overrides the current security configuration with a new implementation. This is meant
 * to be used as a temporary means to alter the behavior of the ESAPI and should *NEVER*
 * be used in a production environment as it will affect the behavior and configuration of
 * the ESAPI *GLOBALLY*.
 *
 * To clear an overridden Configuration, simple call this method with null for the config
 * parameter.
 *
 * @param config
 * @return
 */
public static void override( SecurityConfiguration config ) {
    overrideConfig = config;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tomcat configuration for a specific instance, the first thing that comes to mind is setting it up using tomcat's `setenv.sh` script.  Something like

```
export JAVA_OPTS='$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources="/path/resources"'
```