# ESAPI custom property files

Tags: properties, esapi

Ok, so I've been researching ESAPI for awhile now and trying to determnine how to create custom ESAPI and validator.properties files that override those found in my  ESAPI jar.  How do I accomplish this?  I know it looks in 4 places (reference: [ESAPI properties file in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608638/esapi-properties-file-in-tomcat), ESAPI docs) when trying to load, obviously loading via the classpath works but it's loading the default property values.  I can get my custom properties to load when I put them in my home directory but that isn't very helpful.

Is there a way to get ESAPI to load my custom properties files when they are in my main projects directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608638/esapi-properties-file-in-tomcat  (Yes, question was in tomcat context, but it discusses just about everything...)

Comment: Also note here this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696423/trying-to-use-esapi-but-getting-error

That also gives you a link to one of the default properties files that you should consider starting out with, unless you're just playing with the library.  Many secure defaults have been set up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use

> -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources=PATH_TO_FOLDER

JVM option?